# JAXB XmlJavaTypeAdapter unmarshal method not being called

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb

I am trying to marshal/unmarshal a Color to XML. The JAXB project had example code for doing this exact thing via a XmlJavaTypeAdapter https://jaxb.java.net/guide/XML_layout_and_in_memory_data_layout.html.

The marshaling works fine and the output is what I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<beanWithColor>
    <foreground>#ff0000ff</foreground>
    <name>CleverName</name>
</beanWithColor>
```

However, when trying to go from XML to object the unmarshal method is never called. Can anyone provide insight as to why? After it is unmarshalled foreground color is null and I have confirmed with my debugger that unmarshal is never being called:

```
BeanWithColor{foreground=null, name='CleverName'}
```

SCCE:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BeanWithColor {
private String name;
private Color foreground;

public BeanWithColor() {

}

public BeanWithColor(Color foreground, String name) {
    this.foreground = foreground;
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ColorAdapter.class)
public Color getForeground() {
    return this.foreground;
}

public void setForeground(Color foreground) {
    this.foreground = foreground;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("BeanWithColor{");
    sb.append("foreground=").append(foreground);
    sb.append(", name='").append(name).append('\'');
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeanWithColor bean = new BeanWithColor(Color.blue, "CleverName");

    try {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(1000);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BeanWithColor.class);
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(bean, writer);
        System.out.println("Marshaled XML: " + writer);

        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        BeanWithColor beanWithColor = (BeanWithColor) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(writer.toString()));
        System.out.println("beanWithColor = " + beanWithColor);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static class ColorAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Color> {
    public Color unmarshal(String s) {
        return Color.decode(s);
    }

    public String marshal(Color color) {
        return '#' + Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `XmlAdapter` is being called for `unmarshal`  but that the `Color.decode` method is failing (this is what happens when I debugged your code).

```
Color.decode("#ff0000ff");
```

results in the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ff0000ff"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:528)
    at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:958)
    at java.awt.Color.decode(Color.java:707)
```

You can set a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to get a hook on all failures.  By default a JAXB impl wouldn't report that problem.

**The Fix**

The `ColorAdapter.marshal` method needs to be fixed to return the correct value.

```
String rgb = Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB());
return "#" + rgb.substring(2, rgb.length());
```

Comment: After you said to put a validation handler on it I did and saw the NumberFormatException and was just closing in on the same solution. 0xff0000ff is over MAX_INT and Color.decode() calls Integer.decode().